# Get Selected attachment in outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I am using an addin which enable me to attach a context menu to outlook attachments. So when ever I click on an attachment  I am able to see my custom button in the context menu .

The problem I am facing is, how do I know which attachment is clicked. I have some alternatives in my mind

1. When context menu is opening, I can associate a tag to this context menu. In this tag , i can store the file name of the attachment. Using this file name I can identify the attachment in context_menu_button_click event. Currently I cannot find a place where context menu tells about the object, on which context menu was opened.
2. I loop through some property available in inspector or  any other object which tell me which object, inside the email is selected. For this, I can get to the selected email and I can also iterate through all  attachments, but I cannot figure out which attachment is selected (or right clicked)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316083/extending-the-oulook-2010-attachment-context-menu)

```cs
var attachmentSelection = (control.Context as AttachmentSelection).OfType<Attachment>();
```

Which can be translated into...

```cs
AttachmentSelection attachmentSelection = control.Context as AttachmentSelection;
```

Now using `attachmentSelection` object may solve the problem....!

Answer (score 0):

Use Explorer/Inspector.AttachmentSelection collection.