# Extending the Oulook 2010 attachment context menu

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am extending the contextmenu shown for attachments in Outlook 2010 in xml. So far i've got a button and a handler for the onAction event. Could anybody help me on how to get the currrently selected attachments from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_AttachmentContextMenu

says

> IRibbonControl.Context
>
> AttachmentSelection object

so =>

`var attachmentSelection = (control.Context as AttachmentSelection).OfType<Attachment>();`